# Printing a Shapefile converted to Raster

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

I converted a shapefile into a raster, and it has [odd format](https://i.vgy.me/L3sQ8q.png). When I try to plot it as a raster, colors are based on the id, but I want to figure out how to color it based on the deaths or cases values.

Code:

```r
rasterEmpty = raster(ncol=36000, nrow=18000)
rasterNations = rasterize(nations, rasterEmpty)
plot(rasterNations)
```

I wrote the converted raster to a [.nc file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19UO8EM-Ce93I9SMEIezm_ifEcTWIdJJ2/view?usp=sharing), and when I load it in, it doesn't have the same format.

Comment: Fairly consistent, and likely frustrating problem of getting answers to your questions, while it is clear you are 'wrestling' with it in various iterations, the process here of `data`, `code I tried`, `error that reported`, works. Iif you point to where to download your data of interest (1 `.nc` perhaps), we have a shot at working on the same thing.

Comment: I edited the original post adding a link to a .nc file.  Oddly, the @data field is completely missing.

Comment: I was actually suggesting pointing people to where to download the original data you were trying to use, not the result of the rasterize then write to an .nc file. This puts people at the start of a potential pipeline. Starting in the middle, or end, doesn't leave anything to go back to and try a different approach.

Comment: I cannot send people to the original shapefile because I do not have redistribution rights